# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3):

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, promise, async-await

I am new to await. I just cant figure out how to handle all the await error and rejection. There are always unhandle rejection coming from shopify-api.js function and I can't print all the error coming from the middleware I created index.js?

How can I print all the errors? Am I doing await handling correctly?

index.js

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

const asyncMiddleware = fn => (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.json(err)
         })
           .catch(next)
};


app.get('/v1/Test/Shopify', asyncMiddleware ( async (req, res, next) => {

 req.params.workshopId = "TEST_CR"
 req.params.date = "2018-11-30"
 req.params.startTime = "11:00"
 let result1 = await ShopifyWorkshop.AddDate(req, res, next)
 console.log("ShopifyWorkshop.AddDate: Success" .green)

 res.status(200).json({message: "Success"})
}));
```

```js
exports.AddDate = async (req, res, next) => {
  await Helper.CheckParamsIsNull(req.params)

  let wsId = req.params.workshopId
  let wsDate = req.params.date
  let wsTime = req.params.startTime

  // Check if workshop is a level
  if (Helper.IsWorkshopType(wsId)) {
    return await Promise.all(WORKSHOP_TYPE[wsId].levelNames.map( async (typeName) => {
      WORKSHOP_CATEGORY[typeName].codeNames.map( async (codeName) => {
        for (let wsId in WORKSHOP_INFO) {
          if (WORKSHOP_INFO[wsId].codeName === codeName) {
            addVariant(wsId, wsDate, wsTime)
          }
        }
      })
    }))
  } else if (Helper.IsWorkshopCategory(wsId)) {
    return await Promise.all(WORKSHOP_CATEGORY[wsId].codeNames.map ( async (codeName) => {
    for (let wsId in WORKSHOP_INFO) {
      if (WORKSHOP_INFO[wsId].codeName === codeName) {
        await addVariant(wsId, wsDate, wsTime)
      }
    }
  }))
  } else {     
    return await addVariant(wsId, wsDate, wsTime)
  }
}
```

shopify-api.js

```js
exports.AddAProductVariant = async (id, options) => {
   console.log("Adding variant to product..." + options.option1)

 let result = await shopify.productVariant.create(id, options)

 console.log("Added product variant: " + options.option1)
 return result
}
```

Comment: Here's a great article that might help https://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript/. There are a few options but `try {} catch {}` blocks are the most commen when handling await errors.

Comment: but i have use a middleware to catch all the error so that i dont need a try/catch in every function. am I not doing it right? sorry alittle noob on this

Comment: I see sorry for my misunderstanding :). Hmmm I would need to set this up to test properly. Also this is a great article for promises swallowing errors etc 
http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/.

Comment: You should not need to pass a `next` callback to `AddDate`

Answer (score 0):

In the lines

```
async (typeName) => {
    WORKSHOP_CATEGORY[typeName].codeNames.map( async (codeName) => {
       …
    })
}
```

you are creating an array of promises but then ignore them. Add another `Promise.all` wrapper around them to be able to return a promise for all of them to the outer `map`:

```
(typeName) => {
    return Promise.all(WORKSHOP_CATEGORY[typeName].codeNames.map( async (codeName) => {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       …
    }))
}
```